# Limit number of records in chat when using jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have a chat function with many people and I have a limit on the number of messages displayed to load faster. it is 50.
when i use jmeter to measure chat screen loading speed it is taking all message count from past.
That's not what I want, what I want is to measure the loading speed of the chat screen with the limited number of messages when I set it up above.
So how to set jmeter to load chat limit ??

Answer (score 0):

Just launch JMeter providing the following [command-line option](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

```
jmeter -XdearJMeterpleaserespectmychatmessageslimitof50thankyou -n -t test.jmx
```

---

And now serious, which "chat":

1. Simple [HTTP](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) (i.e. polling)
2. [XMPP](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xmpp-load-testing-the-ultimate-guide)
3. [WebSocket](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)
4. Anything else I cannot think of right now? If yes, what [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols)(s) are in scope? How it's implemented and how real users are getting this "50" messages limit?

Well-behaved JMeter script should produce the same network footprint as the real user of the system under test, if the real user gets 50 mesasges only and JMeter takes more - you need to figure out where exactly this limit can be set, you might need to [contact the plugin developer or maintainer](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins) or amend its code yourself or even [write your own JMeter plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)